# What adjustment can be made to this function for an effective functionality

Tags: javascript, function

I want to define a function which I can use to find the longest word in a sentence. Using this logic below, I still don't understand why it's output isn't correct.

```
function longest_word(string){
string=string.toLowerCase ();
list=string.split(' ') ; 
var i=0;
var  j=1;
while (i<list.length){
if (list[j] .length>list[i].length){
Long_word =list[j] ;
} 
else {
Long_word =list [i];
}
i++;
} 
return Long_word ;
}
```

I want to test my function, so I did the following :

```
f= 'I live in Pennsylvania new York ' 
console.log( longest_word (f)) 
returned  live as the longest_word
```

I thought for a while, then noticed that  there was no increment in my *j variable*
So I did the following making j increase in like manner as i:

```
function longest_word(string){
string=string.toLowerCase ();
list=string.split(' ') ;
var i=0;   
var  j=1;
while (i<list.length){
if (list[j] .length>list[i].length){
Long_word =list[j] ;

 } 
else {
Long_word =list [i];
}
i++;
j++  ;   // j increases by 1
} 
return Long_word ;
} 
f= 'I live in Pennsylvania new York ' 
console.log( longest_word (f))
```

returned this message

```
Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

How can I go about fixing it.. What adjustment should be made on my code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A shorter way: `f.split(' ').reduce(function (acc, val) {return val.length > acc.length ? val : acc;})`.

Comment: @Teemu Looks good and it's short, but unfortunately it's buggy. If the last word is the longest one or equal with any other word in the sentence, it will return it together with a dot.

Comment: @Kinduser I can't see any dot in OP's example. Anyway, you can split by a regexp (`/\b/`), that would fix your "dot issue".

Comment: @teemu...only 3 lines of codes.. Very short indeed...thanks for your response..

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, but you know... sentence usually ends with a dot (: Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What adjustment can be made to this function for an effective functionality?*

I've made an effective function for you, with thoroughly described steps.

```js
var sentence = 'This is a very long sentence with few words.',
    arrOfWords = sentence.slice(0, -1).split(' '), //get rid of the `dot` at the end and split it
    longestWord = '';
    
    arrOfWords.forEach(function(v) { //iterate over every element
      if (v.length > longestWord.length) { //check if element is longer than previous one
        longestWord = v; //if so - replace it
      }
    })
    
    console.log(longestWord); //show result
```

Comment: Your code consumes less memory and time.. Thanks.. Was really helpful